# Using custom tag attributes in Angular directive templates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I've looked at many other questions like this and haven't found one that quite seems to cover what I'm trying to do.

I'm using a template in a directive to create a custom dropdown with fancy stuff like a search box. For this, I have to use `template`; I can't just use `compile` with `element.replaceWith` (I'm able to get this working if I use `compile` with an `attrs` param, but then the custom template doesn't work).

All I want to do is select a particular array of options depending on the contents of an attribute in my custom tag:

HTML: `<customdropdown useoptionset="first"></customdropdown>`

JS:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap', [])

.constant('customdropdownConfig', {
    //bunch of properties here
})

.directive('customdropdown ', ['$parse', 'customdropdownConfig', function ($compile, customdropdownConfig) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        template: (function(conf) {
            var optionset = //how can i access the useoptionset attribute here?

            var options = //stuff involving useoptionset and conf

            return '<select ui-select="customDropdown">' + options + '</select>';
        }(customdropdownConfig))
    };
}])
```

It seems to me that this should be a very common and obvious use case, but maybe I'm missing something about how Angular works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the template much more simple and then using the linking function to add dynamic content to the `<select>` element.

Like this:

```
.directive('customdropdown ', ['$parse', 'customdropdownConfig', function ($compile, customdropdownConfig) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        template: '<select ui-select="customDropdown"></select>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            var optionset = attrs.optionset;
            var options = //stuff involving useoptionset and conf
            elem.html(options);
            $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
        }
    };
}]);
```

It sounds like you may have tried this already, but I can't see why it wouldn't work.  If it doesn't, maybe you could give more explanation of what you've tried so far and why it hasn't worked.

Comment: probably the reason i couldn't get it to work was that i'm still relatively new to angular and wasn't really sure how to use templates and linking functions (looks like i was trying to combine the functionality of both into `template`). it's amazing how much your example alone clears things up - thanks, i'm sure that will work. i'll give this a shot tomorrow.